# Is there a NULL value for a multi-value list?

Tags: 8, feeds

I have a list that accepts 5 different values, but some things on my spreadsheet are empty, meaning its none of the 5 things. However during the feeds import, it is saying my empty field is not a valid selection.

Is there a way I can still import even though the value is empty?

Comment: Yes, its key is `_none`

Comment: So with feeds tamper I set defaule value to _none if field is empty, but it still says its  not a valid choice.

Comment: Ok try using the label, by putting `- None -`

Answer (score 0):

[Select Element's API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Select.php/8.9.x)

> #empty_option: (optional) The label to show for the first default option. By default, the label is automatically set to "- Select -" for
> a required field and "- None -" for an optional field.
>
> #empty_value: (optional) The value for the first default option, which is used to determine whether the user submitted a value or not.

So using this information, you are able to use the null value's defaults from the select element.